# How do Site URL Redirects work?

Tags: force.com-sites, url, redirect, custom-url

I am currently working for a company that is in the middle of a name change and we are changing the My Domain as well as our custom URLs to the new name. I would like to redirect previous custom URLs with the old name to the new name custom URLs while referencing the record ID of our donation pages – but I’ve been unable to test successfully in Sandbox.

Below is an example of my Site URL Redirect…

Source URL: /donate/?id={Donation_Page__c.Id}

Redirect Type: Permanent (301)

Target URL (not the actual target): https://fulltest-xyztest.cs59.force.com/mwdonate/?id={Donation_Page__c.Id}

Is my Source URL incorrect? Or maybe where I have the Site URL Redirect (under the MWDonate which is the new site)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do isn't currently possible from a Sandbox. See the below link:

Test Your Custom Domains in a Sandbox (Pilot): 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_mgmt_sandbox_custom_domains.htm&type=5